# How to create new row at every 49th column from the dataframe in .log file (in R)?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to import .log file using read.table in R

below is a sample (Except of the test.log)
20410088416;5268;1;5251;1;253;3;2;-8.101;25.00;3.250;1;32.00;55.00;59;0;0.100;0.000;0.000;2.216;-9.315;25.00;3.250;1;30.00;30.00;50;0;0;0;-192.633;-35.912;-8.026;-194.842;-35.729;-9.264;0;;42;1;0,0...

I have attached the test.log is here (https://www.dropbox.com/s/pki7wkwdtxy2gcc/test.log?dl=0)

```
log<- read.table("test.log", sep=";")
```

The output log shows 1 obs of 10560 variables. The desired output would be 220 obs of 48 columns.
How can I make use of this read such that every 49th column will be index to another new row in R?
I tried to reshape function and other methods here it did not work. hope there is more efficient way to solve this problem.

**thanks in advance for your sharing and help.**

Edited:
Note that they are , within the dataset  - I consider them as strings under 1 column. I'd like to output to be (see img below):

[target output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QokS6.png)

Comment: Ideally you should fix this while reading itself because the other approach is error-prone. Can you post first few rows and columns of `test.log` ?

Comment: Hi Shah -- below is the excerpt of text.log - i have use ";" as my delimiter in this application.
 20412345;82500;2;5341;1;252;3;2;-8.101;25.00;3.250;1;32.00;55.00;59;0;0.100;0.000;0.000;2.303;-9.315;25.00;3.250;1;30.00;30.00;50;0;0;0;-192.700;18.739;-8.015;-194.996;18.927;-9.237;0;;48;1;0,0,0,-2,-11,-24,-38,-48,-54,-58,-60,-61,-63,-64,-64,-65,-67,-68,-69,-70,-72,-73,-75,-76,-78,-79,-81,-83,-85,-87,-89,-90...etc

Comment: please add this data in your question, not in comments

Comment: you also seem to have something that is delimited with a `,` in your log? can show what your desired output looks like?

Comment: thanks monte/ otto - first time trying to use stackoverflow, will do better next time!

Answer (score 0):

Not the most optimum, but try this:

```
sep_in_rows <- seq(from = 1, to = ncol(log), by = 48)
y <- vector()

for(i in 2:length(sep_in_rows)){
  first_index <- sep_in_rows[i-1]
  second_index <- sep_in_rows[i]
  y <- as.data.frame(rbind(y, log[first_index:second_index]))
}
```